# How can I set an item as activated in sidebar using html,css,php

Tags: php, html, css

I have this sidebar

[image]

and I want an item to be activated by changing its color to white and icon to black when it's selected

**This is what I have tried so far**

***Css Code***

```
.sidebar li a {

  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #76b852;
}
.sidebar li a:hover{
  background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar li a.active{
    background-color: #FFF;
  color: white;
}
```

***Html code***

```
 <li <?php if($currentFile=="dashboard.php"){?>class="active"<?php }?>>
                    <a href="dashboard.php">
                        <i class="material-icons">
                            <span class="material-icons">dashboard</span>
                        </i>
                        <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
                </li>
```

and the problem seems to be here

```
.sidebar li a.active{
background-color: #FFF; 
color: white;}
```

when I add "l" only without "a", the activated items displays as in the following screenshot

[image]

I have got no experience in web development, hope someone helps me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code:

```php
<li <?php if($currentFile=="dashboard.php"){?>class="active"<?php }?>>
```

You add the `active` class to the `li` element.
Because of this, the CSS must also have the `active` class on the `li` element, not the `a` link.

```css
.sidebar li.active a {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: white;
}
```

You may need to add `.sidebar li.active a:hover`, `.sidebar li.active a:active`, depending.
But first let's fix the `.active` selector in the wrong spot.

Comment: thank you so much